# How to access the subscriptions inside the HTML file?

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

Usually when I use helpers, I can access the returned values as below:

```
Template.oveview.helpers({
    item: function () {
        return Requests.find({});
    },
```

Then in the client side I can use `{{#each item}}`, But I don't know how to display them in the `.html` when using `publish` and `subscribe`

Here is my publish:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
    Meteor.publish('requests', function queryRequests() {
        return Requests.find({});
    });

});
```

And here is my subscribe:

```
Template.overview.onCreated(function() {
    Meteor.subscibe('requests');
});
```

How can I display the returned value from publish in the client side?

Comment: The `publish` and `subscribe` you use in the `onCreated` callback will just influence what will return the function `Requests.find({});` You have nothing to change. PS: you've misspelled `subscribe` in your code

Answer (score 1):

You can use it in a few different ways. You can use Meteor templates to insert a HTML snippet for every item in-between existing HTML:

```
{{#each item}}
    {{> htmlTemplateName}}
{{/each}}
```

Or you can just place raw HTML in the `{{#each}}` loop:

```
{{#each item}}
    <p>{{propertyX}}</p>
    <p>{{propertyY}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

You might run into problems with the pubsub, depending on load order (I don't know load orders, I'm afraid). I used the `iron-router` package in my project, to bind certain end-points to specific HTML files. iron-router has this nice parameter you can set for every page, called `waitOn`, where I placed my subscriptions. This means that subscribing to a certain collection happens before anything else.

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: '_layoutTemplate',
    name: 'myTemplateName',
    waitOn: function() {
        return [
            Meteor.subscribe('requests'),
            //Add other subscriptions here
        ];
    }
});
```

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear of what I want. Sorry for the poor clarification at first. I want to display the returned value from publish

Comment: The returned value from your publish is the collection. Or do you want to return the cursor that leads to the collection?

Comment: I want to be able to display the collection in the client side. I can do that if I return the collection from the helper in the client. But I thought that it would be more secure to use publish and subscribe. but I can't seem to be able to display them in the client side.

Comment: @BehrouzRiahi As @Magicbjørn has shown you, you just have to show document fields in `{{#each ...}}...{{/each}}` loop.